# ArrayAdapter for android programming in Java, String array

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I'm using an ArrayAdapter to populate a listview with some string values. For testing purposes I have:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order_list);  
        ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredientArray = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
        Ingredient test1 = new Ingredient();
        Ingredient test2 = new Ingredient();
        test1.testObject1();
        test2.testObject2();
        ingredientArray.add(test1);
        ingredientArray.add(test2);
        String names[] = {test1.getName(), test2.getName()};

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));

    }
```

the two functions testObject1, testObject2 set the value of name to 'A' and 'B' respectively, but when the ListView activity starts, it show 'B' twice, rather than what I expect which would be 'A' first, then 'B'. How can I modify this code so it works properly?

Comment: have you check the names[] array. just check it once by print it as System.out.println(names[0]+" "+names[1]). I think there is a problem with your testObject1() and testObject2().

Comment: Post your testObject1 and testObject2 code.